# How to change the numbering of lemas, theorems, propositions... etc.?

Tags: numbering, chapters, newtheorem

So actually, I am working with the class of MastersDoctoralThesis whose info you can find [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis).
In it, I defined the theorem, lemmas, examples, definitions, corolaries, etc. format as

```
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]
```

However, suppose we are in section 2.4, then everything gets numbered as:

Theorem 2.4.1

Theorem 2.4.2

Lemma 2.4.1

Example 2.4.1

Lemma 2.4.2

My question is if there is a way to change it, for it to look like this:

Theorem 2.4.1

Theorem 2.4.2

Lemma 2.4.3

Example 2.4.4

Lemma 2.4.5

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can process which shows what you have done and what your problem is. In general we will not go to websites where their content might change or dissapear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *amsthm* package docs:

The numbering mechanism can be thought of this way:

```
 \newtheorem{env name}{text}[parent counter] 
 \newtheorem{env name}[shared counter]{text}
```

The *parent counter* is comparable to \numberwithin; that is, numbering will
restart whenever that sectional level is encountered. If a *shared counter* is
specified, numbering will progress sequentially for all theorem elements using
this counter.

By default each kind of theorem-like environment is numbered independently. Thus if you have three lemmas and two theorems interspersed, they
will be numbered something like this:

- Lemma 1
- Lemma 2
- Theorem 1
- Lemma 3
- Theorem 2.

If you want lemmas and theorems to share the same numbering sequence, then you should use the *shared counter* to indicate the desired relationship as follows:

```
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
```

The optional argument [thm] in the second statement means that the lem
environment should share the thm numbering sequence instead of having its
own independent sequence.

To have a theorem environment numbered subordinately within a sectional
unit, e.g., to get propositions numbered Proposition 2.1, Proposition 2.2, and
so on in Section 2, put the name of the parent unit in square brackets in final
position:

```
 \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
```

With the optional argument [section], the prop counter will be reset to 0
whenever the parent counter section is incremented, and the proposition heading will have the section number prepended.

If any theorem elements are numbered by section, and (in a book) the first
such element in a chapter comes before the first section, numbering will continue
from the previous chapter. In such a case, reset the counter by invoking this
command before the affected element:

```
 \setcounter{thm}{0}
```

In your case you should use a *shared counter* and define a custom counter or just use the *subsection* counter like this:

```
 \newtheorem{theo}[subsection]{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{lemma}[subsection]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{ex}[subsection]{Example}
```

Comment: OMG! It worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question, when doing that the subsubsections will follow the numbering given by the theorems, lemmas, etc. I could fix this by using \newtheorem{lemma}[subsubsection]{Lemma}. However not all my sections will have subsubsections and so, doing that globally will leave me with a bunch of Theorem.2.0.1, Lemma.3.0.5, etc. Is there a way in which I can have some sections counted by subsection and others by subsubsection?

Comment: Try creating your own counter.